# Pasting new data below previously pasted data in my macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following program which copies data from one sheet then pastes the transpose of that data from distinct rows to another.
I am running into an issue from when I run the program multiple times it does not paste the new data below the previous ones in the destination sheet, instead, it just pastes over the previous data.

I am unsure how to make this happen and in addition, for the last value in the Array "DSCR" it does not copy the second instance if "DSCR" in the column only the first one.

```
Option Explicit


Sub Extract()

    Dim arr, i As Long, f As Range, cPaste As Range, col As Long
    
    Dim wbPaste As Workbook, wsPaste As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet, wSrc As Workbook
    
    arr = Array("DSCR Analysis", "Commercial Income", "Rental Income", "Other Income", _
            "Total All Income", "Rental Vacancy (%)", "Rental Vacancy ($)", _
            "Commercial Vacancy (%)", "Concessions/Bad Debt (%)", "Concessions/Bad Debt ($)", _
            "Effective Gross Income", "Total Expenses", "NOI", "Facility A Contractual Rate", _
            "MBI Debt Service", "Excess Cash Flow", "DSCR")
               Set wSrc = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MBI DSCR")
    Set wbPaste = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\bbarineau\OneDrive - Merchants Bancorp\Desktop\LBM_DSCT_DataLake.xlsm")
    Set wsPaste = wbPaste.Sheets(1) 'for example
 
     col = wsSrc.Columns.Find(What:="MBI", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
    
    Set cPaste = wsPaste.Range("C1") 'first header cell for pasted values
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        
        cPaste.Value = arr(i) 'add the header
        Set f = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:=arr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        If i = 17 Then
        f = wsSrc.Columns(col).FindNext(f)
        End If
        
        
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6).Copy 'copy 6 columns next to the found cell
            cPaste.Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                             Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        End If
        
        Set cPaste = cPaste.Offset(0, 1) 'next paste destination
    Next i

    wsPaste.Range("A1").Value = "Date Added"
    wsPaste.Range("B1").Value = "Name"
    
    Rows.AutoFit
    Columns.AutoFit
    wbPaste.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of existing "find last used row" questions here on SO - use one of the approaches from those and change the line

```
Set cPaste = wsPaste.Range("C1")
```

to something like

```
Set cPaste = wsPaste.Cells(LastRow+1, "C")
```

Eg of finding last used row:

```
LastRow = wsPaste.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=wsPaste.range("a1"), _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```